# Implicit parameter not found on function application

Tags: function, scala, implicit-conversion

If I define a print function that only takes numbers as:

```
def print[T <% Number](value:T) {}
print: [T](value: T)(implicit evidence$1: (T) => java.lang.Number)Unit
```

I can call the above with:

```
print(5)
print(5.5)
print(6L)
```

But not with a String:

```
print("aaa")  
<console>:7: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type (java.lang.String) => java.lang.Number
       print("aaa")
```

This is expected.

But if I define the print function as:

```
def print2[T <% Number]: T => Unit = value => { } 
print2: [T](implicit evidence$1: (T) => java.lang.Number)(T) => Unit
```

Notice how the implicit parameter is the first parameter instead of the last.

If I try to manually define the above function:

```
def print3[T](implicit f: (T) => java.lang.Number)(value:T):Unit =  { }  
<console>:1: error: '=' expected but '(' found.
       def print3[T](implicit f: (T) => java.lang.Number)(value:T):Unit =  { }
```

Basically the above is not a valid function definition but the compiler creates it when I previously defined print2.

When I call print2 with an Int:

```
print2(5)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(5)
 required: (?) => java.lang.Number
       print2(5)
```

if I parameterize it:

```
print2[Int](5)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(5)
 required: (Int) => java.lang.Number
       print2[Int](5)
```

It looks like it can't find the implicit conversion from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer.

How can I redefine print such that it returns functions and also accesses implicits in the correct way?

Comment: You are confusing methods with functions. Read up on their differences.

Comment: Search stack overflow. I'm on my phone, so it's difficult for me to look up the references.

Comment: I think this is probably an accident of the `scalac` implementation. If you think about it, implicit parameters at any position other than the end makes no sense. Let's say this is allowed `def foo(implicit i: Int)(j: Float)(implicit: k: Int)(l: Double) = ...`. What exactly does it mean for the application `foo(1)(2)(3)` ? It's ambigious.

Comment: I agree. Implicits should be the last parameter.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you are passing 5 *as* the implicit parameter.

Now that I'm on a computer, a few corrections:

```
def print[T <% Number](value:T) {}
```

You call this a *function*, but it is a *method*.

```
def print2[T <% Number]: T => Unit = value => { }
```

Again, you call this a function. Actually, it is a *method* which *returns* a function. The method receives one type parameter, `T`, and one implicit parameter.

```
print2(5)
```

So, here, you call the method `print2` passing `5` as its implicit parameter. The type `T` hasn't been infered yet because it is first trying to conform `5` to the expected type `T => Number`. However, since `5` doesn't conform to `Function1[T, Number]`, it fails without even inferring `T`.

There are many ways to call `print2`. For example:

```
print2(implicitly[Int => Number])
print2[Int]
(print2: Int => Unit)
val f: Int => Unit = print2
```

However, to call the function that is returned by `print2`, you have to avoid making `(5)` look like the implicit parameter to the method `print2`. There's actually only one case above that needs something different:

```
print2(implicitly[Int => Number])(5)
print2[Int].apply(5)
(print2: Int => Unit)(5)
val f: Int => Unit = print2; f(5)
```

Now, most of these examples have explicit, instead of inferred, type parameters.  Let's consider what would happen in its absence:

```
print2.apply(5)
```

Because no parameter was passed to `print2`, it selects the most specific type that conforms to the bounds of `T`. Since `T` has no bounds, `Nothing` is chosen. It then tries to find an implicit `Nothing => Unit`. Because there's no such implicit, it fails.

The parameter to the function that would be returned by `print2` is never looked into to help type inference.

Comment: How do I call print2 such that the implicit parameter is used?

Comment: I can call it like: print2(implicitly[Int => java.lang.Number])(5). Hardly the nicest solution.

Comment: @ssanj you can use print2[Int].apply(5), though I realize that is unlikely to be what you want. However, you want the language to work in a way it doesn't.